# Sonar null pointer violations

Tags: java, excel, collections, apache-poi

Sonar giving below null pointer violations for below line

existed.keySet()

Please could you help us to resolve this issue.

```
    private boolean isEqualCaptions(Map<String, String> existed, Map<String, String> updated) {

        if(existed == null && updated != null) return false;
        if(existed != null && updated == null) return false;
        for(String key:existed.keySet()){
            if(existed.get(key).compareTo(updated.get(key)) != 0) return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What if `existed == null && updated == null`?

Comment: If both `existed` and `updated` are nulls, your code can't possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

If `existed` and `updated` are both `null`,
then the program will reach the loop, and `existed.keySet()` will throw a `NullPointerException`, that's why you get the warning.

Before the loop, you should add a condition to make sure `existed` is not `null`.

```
private boolean isEqualCaptions(Map<String, String> existed, Map<String, String> updated) {
    if (existed == null && updated != null) return false;
    if (existed != null && updated == null) return false;
    if (existed != null) {
        for (String key : existed.keySet()) {
            if (existed.get(key).compareTo(updated.get(key)) != 0) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Finally, the condition `A && !B || !A && B` can be simplified using the XOR operator as `A ^ B`, so the first two `if` statements can be combined and simplified:

```
private boolean isEqualCaptions(Map<String, String> existed, Map<String, String> updated) {
    if (existed == null ^ updated == null) return false;
    if (existed != null) {
        for (String key : existed.keySet()) {
            if (existed.get(key).compareTo(updated.get(key)) != 0) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @PM77-1 after adding a check for `existed != null`, we know that `updated` cannot be `null`, because if it was, the function would have returned earlier.